# Why redefine pListPath in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, nsbundle

So I've read a ton of SO-questions about plists and how to save to them, and although I don't know, why no iPhone-Dev-Book I've seen so far covered this (they all used the tableView editing function), I managed to REALLY write to a plist by copying it to the documents folder like this:

```
pListPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
pListPath = [pListPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"piggyBanks.plist"];
NSLog(@"Path: %@", pListPath);

// if the file does not exist yet, create it, and copy the plist data into it, that can be found in the bundle 
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pListPath]) {
    NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"piggyBanks" ofType:@"plist"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:pListPath error:nil]; 
}

// make the plist content available for usage
pListContent = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pListPath];
NSLog(@"pListContent: %@", pListContent);
```

So far so good, but now, if I wanna change some plist value when a user taps on a tableViewCell (it's a custom one, if that's important), although `pListPath`, `pListContent` and others are properties, defined in .h and synthesized in .m, I have to redefine `pListPath` and `pListContent` inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, to get the path to be known in that moment.

Could someone please tell me why? I mean, it's nice, that it works, but I'd like to know, why it has to be like that, or if I did a mistake somewhere else..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled for class variables in objective C, and found my way through various articles, till i found [this](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/2/8/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html) blog/blogpost, which explains the self. and _underscore thing really well! 
I now always declare my Ivars with an underscore, the properties without. Works out quite well. And to sum it up, why to ALWAYS use self.yourPropertiesName, you are calling a method (setter and getter)! And like any other method you are calling, you need to say, who is calling.

Hope this will help someone else too :)

Answer (score 0):

If `plistPath` is a string property of your class, you need to assign it as such:

```
if (!self.pListPath)    
{
    NSString *newPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    newPath = [newPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"piggyBanks.plist"];
    self.pListPath = newPath;
}
```

Then afterwards, use `self.pListPath` instead of `pListPath`.

You are having to re-set it because at the moment, `pListPath` is being assigned to an autoreleased string which will have been removed by the time you need it again. Setting the property (assuming the property is retained or copied) will retain the string for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I'm not sure, if I got it. I tried your way (you mixed sth. in line 4, it should be newPath after the = ), and surprisingly it works. But isn't it an object variable if I use self.pListPath, instead of a class variable? I introduced pListPath like `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *pListPath;`, and had it as `assign` before. I think I remember using other types without self. as a class variable..

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, I've updated the answer. I'm not sure what you mean regarding class and object variables - those aren't really terms used in objective C. You want the path to be an _instance variable_ which is what it is. Accessing it via self. just means you go through the accessors - particulary important for the setter because it retains the variable for you.

Comment: Well, I learned it like there are class variables and object variables. Class V. are the same for every object of a particular class, while Object Vs. are different for every object of a class, although every object definitely has this variable. Class Vs. get called simply by the vars name, while object Vs. get called like self.varName, maybe that's confusing me.. (I'm coming from a C++ background, thought this would apply in objC too). So is it the other way around in objC? Everything with self.varName is the same for every object of a class, while varName without self. is like an object V.?

Comment: No, it's not the same in objective C. The closest to what you call class variables are probably static variables in objective C. I'd go over the introdcution to objective C documentation on the apple developer site if I were you, I'm unlikely to give you the best answer!